# Javascript - Hide only on parent click

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a simple markup:

```
<div id="edit_image" class="image_manipulator">
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

And this is the javascript:

```
var image_manipulators= document.getElementsByClassName("image_manipulator");
for(var i = 0; i < image_manipulators.length; i++) {
    image_manipulators[i].onclick = function() {
        this.style.display = "none";
    };
}
```

And this is the CSS:

```
.image_manipulator {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
}
#edit_image input {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mareebsiddiqui/XVS2C/).

If you click on the translucent box then you can see that it disappears normally but if you try to write something on the textbox then still the translucent box disappears. How can I stop that from happening. :)

P.S: No jQUery allowed. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try event.stopPropagation();

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XVS2C/3/)**

**html**

```
<div id="edit_image" class="image_manipulator">
    <input id="textBox" type="text" />
</div>
<button id="showBox">Click me</button>
```

**Java Script**

```
var image_manipulators = document.getElementsByClassName("image_manipulator");
for (var i = 0; i < image_manipulators.length; i++) {
    image_manipulators[i].onclick = function () {
        this.style.display = "none";
    };
}

document.getElementById("showBox").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("edit_image").style.display = "block";
}

document.getElementById("textBox").onclick = function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, worked. :) Actually I enhanced it a little. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/mareebsiddiqui/XVS2C/5/

Comment: Great! Hope it helps :)

Comment: To expand on the answer and to why it works, it is that when you click on  "textBox" that is not the end of the event, the event percolates up through all the parent nodes all the way to `document`, unless you explicitly `stopPropagation()` like Pravin has done here.

Comment: Thanks for additional Info! to be honest It was not so crystal clear before your explanation.

Comment: @PravinVaichal - seem my comment to iwcoder's answer :)

Answer (score 1):

you should cancel the default behavior when click in input, see http://jsfiddle.net/XVS2C/8/

```
document.getElementById("test").onclick = function( e ){
if (!e)
  e = window.event;

//IE9 & Other Browsers
if (e.stopPropagation) {
  e.stopPropagation();
}
//IE8 and Lower
  else {
   e.cancelBubble = true;
  }
}
```

set an id to input

```
<input type="text" id="test" />
```

Comment: If you are looking at this and Pravin's answer and wondering whats the deal with `cancelBubble` vs `stopPropagation` check out http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Comment: just made some changes for all browsers, previous version only works with IE and chrome. take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/XVS2C/8/

Answer (score 0):

try using this:

`var image_manipulators= document.getElementsByClassName("image_manipulator");
for(var i = 0; i < image_manipulators.length; i++) {
    image_manipulators[i].onclick = function(e) {
        this.style.display = "none";
        e.stopPropagation();
    };
}`

Comment: I don't think that's going to solve. Doesn't work :/